# Unable to install i3 on Debian stretch

Tags: debian, apt, i3, software-updates

I'd like to try out the i3 window manager. When I run `apt-get install i3` I run into the following error;

```
root@hammerhead:~# apt-get install i3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package i3
```

Here's a copy of `/etc/apt/sources.list`;

```
root@hammerhead:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.3.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20171209-12:10]/ stretch contrib main non-free

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.3.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20171209-12:10]/ stretch contrib main non-free

deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just able to install i3 on Debian Stretch using these repositories:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main          
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
```

Try using these repositories and running `apt-get update`.